# iTextSharp not creating form for PDF

Tags: c#, pdf-generation, itext

Right now I am using iTextSharp to create a PDF. We have a need to put a few text boxes on this PDF for the user to fill out. The PDF if being generated dynamically since it depends on user input as to what is shown, which can increase or decrease page count depending on what is selected. When we use iTextSharp, adobe sees the fields, but says "Currently there are no form fields in this PDF....". If I hit cancel on this dialog, I see the fields are on the PDF, but something is not right. I loaded up the PDF in a trial of Aspose.PDF and it can't see the fields either. I am adding the fields in the code sample below.

```
            var txtName1 = writer.AcroForm.AddSingleLineTextField("Name1","",_avenirDefault,Font.NORMAL, 72, writer.GetVerticalPosition(false) - 12, 275,writer.GetVerticalPosition(false) + 5);
        txtName1.SetFieldFlags(PdfFormField.FF_REQUIRED);
```

I have also tried,

```
            var txtName1 = new TextField(writer,
                                new Rectangle(72, writer.GetVerticalPosition(false) - 12, 275,
                                              writer.GetVerticalPosition(false) + 5), "Name1") { Options = BaseField.REQUIRED };
writer.AddAnnotation(txtName1 );
```

Neither of these prevented the error from showing in Adobe or finding the fields in the Aspose library. Any idea why these fields are shown but not detected as Form Fields for adobe?

Comment: The latter way (using `new TextField` and `AddAnnotation`) looks like it should work; all the contextual code is missing, though, so I cannot tell for sure. Thus, please provide a simple, self contained bit of code and a sample PDF Adobe and Aspose have trouble with.

Comment: No it shouldn't work! You can't a add a TextField as an annotation. You need writer.AddAnnotation(txtName1.GetTextField()); to change the TextField instance into a PdfFormField instance.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie the writer.AcroForm.AddSingleLineTextField does this for you. I checked the iTextSharp source code and it does the addannotation with the GetTextField(). We also tried adding two text fields with .AddKid to another text field and then adding that. It didn't work. The strange thing is it worked on another PDF. Each PDF has around 1500 lines of code, so I can't share that with SO.

Comment: When you say "it worked with another PDF", do you mean you are trying to add fields to existing PDFs? If you do, then `PdfWriter` is the wrong class for you...

Comment: @BrunoLowagie I meant another PDF as another dynamically generated from scratch PDF. Not an existing one. We copied the code from that generation to this code and it fails.